# php array_column function, how to use index_key

Tags: php, function

I'm using the php function

```
$array = [ 'red' => ['nice' => true, 'hot' => true], 'green => ['nice' => true, 'hot' => false ]

array array_column ( array $array , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )
```

and I want to set the index_key to be the array index, how to do that ?

```
array_column($array, 'hot' , index??? )
```

to get

```
 [  
     'red' => true,
     'green' => false
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_column() allows you to define an element from the child array as your key, but not the key of the child array; it works with values from the child array.

What you can do though is:

```
$result = array_combine(
    array_keys($originalArray),
    array_column($originalArray, 'hot')
);
```